# So how is setting your editor to display #-space tab indents not a better solution than using spaces for indents?

Tags: tabs, editor, spaces

Every time I have to work with space indents, it's a giant time-consuming cumbersome mistake-prone burden.

I've discovered in every editor I've used that I can just set how many spaces a tab shows, switch to tabs, and have never run into a problem other than someone telling me I should be using spaces but without pointing out any actual problem it's caused other than annoying them because they've decided they have to use spaces.

I also haven't found an editor that will display indents a certain way but save them the preferred group-think way, though I did find something about using git to checkout/commit either way.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too deep in the tabs vs spaces debate, one key reason to use spaces is that it will render the same in every IDE and everywhere else (printed page, web browser, etc).

Now, when it comes to an editor that sets tab size:

- if it converts tabs to spaces (aka soft tabs), then there is no difference. you're perfectly fine using tabs in your editor as long as you set the tab width to equal the number of spaces others use, and others have no right to tell you how to use your editor.
- if it simply sets the tab size to render the equivalent to 4 spaces, but retains the tab key (hard tabs), then you run into problems. it leads to readability issues, so in the name of being a team-working, considerate developer, you'll want to just use spaces.

I think most editors will default to soft tabs, so you're fine there. Just double check that your editor is indeed using soft tabs rather than hard, and tell others to mind their own business.

Comment: It's not just that "it will render the same in every IDE", it's also that it will render the same _outside_ an IDE.  On a printed page, in diff or patch output, in email, in a browser, ...

Comment: Readability has been an issue with 2-space indents, which I've seen the majority of the time with recent coders (probably due to shrinking screen sizes), and which is why I asked the question. Frankly I'm still finding in real-world usage more complications using space indents than tabs than I am with people configuring their editors to parse indents properly, so I don't consider it an editor issue.